# Remote desktop to Bitlocker encrypted computer

Tags: remote-desktop, bitlocker

I was just required to enable Bitlocker full disk encryption on my work computer (Win 10). I travel frequently and use remote desktop to remote into the work computer from a computer used while traveling. As long as the work computer is on, this is no problem. It has been working with the Bitlocker computer, but a recent software update was pushed to the work computer and required it to be restarted. Now I can't get into the computer because the Bitlocker screen to access the computer is not accessible via the remote desktop which requires Windows to be running, which it isn't until the Bitlocker key is entered.

Is there any idea on how to get this to work? This is a direct computer-to-computer remote desktop connection, no network involved.

Comment: If your talking about the recovery key prompt there is absolutely to way to bypass it.  You will have to provide the key.  If you do not have the key the only workaround is a full format and to reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get past the BitLocker recovery key prompt screen until someone types it in manually in front of the PC. This has been the bain of many IT personnel's existence